# How could the Crocus City Hall in Krasnogorsk burn to ashes if it was not wooden?

Tags: fire

During the recent terrorist attack in Russia, the terrorists operated in the building for about 18 min. How could they set it on fire in such short time so that it burned to ashes and the roof collapsed?

The footage from outside shows very energetic fire and parts of the building flying away. According to reports, the fire was with efforts "localized" in the area of 4000 square meters.

From my experience, it could be  problematic to set on fire a pile of wood in such short time.

So, how this could be possible if the terrorsts at most had backpacks with them?

Comment: explosives were used

Comment: Anything melts / burns if you get it hot enough.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Wikipedia article on the attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crocus_City_Hall_attack) the attackers used incendiary devices, at points chosen to trap people inside the building.  Also according to the article, the roof collapsed hours later.

So "how did they set it on fire in such a short time?" -- the fires were started locally, and they were small when set.  Even a steel and concrete buildings have healthy fuel loads -- carpets, wiring, wall decoration, furniture, etc. -- so once things got going the fire would have been sustained by the structure and contents of the building itself.

> From my experience, it could be problematic to set on fire a pile of wood in such short time.

- Pile up a bunch of wood, into a pile as tall as you, fairly well packed but with room for air to flow none the less, intermixed with carpet or upholstered chairs.
- Dump two gallons of gasoline on it, where it'll soak at least one of the chairs.
- Toss in a match.
- Report back

  - (don't get arrested).